# how to quickly open browser showing instructional text, in ASP.NET VisualBasic2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I easily open a new browser with just some help text in it?

I want to make a function that takes help text as an argument, and all it does is open a new browser showing the help text.

Then, I can put linkbuttons on my web app wherever help is needed, so the user can popup these browsers with help instructions for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you should make it on the client side, not on the server side. It will be something like a javascript function that opens a new browser window like this:

```
openHelp('Hello from JavaScript!');
function openHelp(content) {
 top.helpWindow=window.open('','myconsole',
  'width=350,height=250'
   +',menubar=0'
   +',toolbar=1'
   +',status=0'
   +',scrollbars=1'
   +',resizable=1')
 top.helpWindow.document.writeln(
  '<html><head><title>Console</title></head>'
   +'<body bgcolor=white onLoad="self.focus()">'
   +content
   +'</body></html>'
 )
 top.helpWindow.document.close()
}
```